# can not remove field from serializer with .pop('field') in create() method - DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework. I want to create admin endpoint where the user can add the member with project permission. following is the data coming from the user.

```
{
  "email" : "name@yopmail.com",
  "first_name" : "asd",
  "last_name" : "asd",
  "projects":[{
     "project_id" : 1,
     "project_role" : 1 },
   { "project_id" : 1,
     "project_role" : 1
  }],
  "position" : "something something"
}
```

following is serializer I created to validate and save the data.

```
class ProjectPermissionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
        Serialiser to hold permissions pair of project_id and role
    """
    project_id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=False)
    project_role = serializers.ChoiceField(PROJECT_ROLES)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass


class ProjectMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
        serializer to add new member with projects
    """

    projects = ProjectPermissionSerializer(many=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name',  'last_name', 'email', 'position', 'projects')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        permission_data = validated_data.pop('projects')
        emailstatus = {"email_id": validated_data.pop('email')}
        emailobj, created = EmailStatus.objects.get_or_create(**emailstatus)
        validated_data['email'] = emailobj
        project_member = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return project_member
```

still, after popping the projects from validated_data, I'm getting following error.

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `projects` on serializer `ProjectMemberSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'projects'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Your model dont have field named projects, in this case you need to specify source of the field, to link serializer's field with model's field e.g. 'project_set':

```
 projects = ProjectPermissionSerializer(many=True, source='project_set')
```

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations I following this. I did not need to save projectsPermissionSerializer to the database. I will just run it in for loop inside the create function.

Comment: @Aniketpatel in provided example `profile` is model's field. To add writable field to ModelSerializer you need to specify source which is model's field or property.